# Split if one or more spaces are found

Tags: javascript, regex, syntax

I'm confused about something I read on devdocs.io.

```
var names = "Harry Trump ;Fred Barney; Helen Rigby ; Bill Abel ;Chris Hand ";

print(names);

var re = /\s*;\s*/;
var nameList = names.split(re);

   print(nameList);
```

I'm having a tough time understanding this. I know how to split with one character or space and I know this is to split if multiple spaces are found. I just can't figure out what the "var re" syntax means. I'm sorry this is kind of a beginner question but I can't find any resources on stackoverflow or google to clarify this for me.

Comment: It's a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: To be precise, it is a [Regular Expression Literal](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're probably struggling with the regular expression.

```
var re = /\s*;\s*/;
```

the regular expression is constructed between those slashes `/`, so basically you need to figure out what `\s*;\s*` means.

`\s` = any white-space character.

`*` = repeat the previous character in a sequence zero-times-or-more.

`;` = just the ';' character.

so the overall is: a sequence of zero-times-or-more of any white-space, followed immediately by a `;` and then again a sequence of zero-times-or-more of any white-space.

if your string is `Harry Trump ;Fred Barney; Helen Rigby ; Bill Abel ;Chris Hand`
then, after the splitting it should be `Harry Trump` `Fred Barney` `Helen Rigby` `Bill Abel` `Chris Hand`

Answer (score 0):

It's not special syntax. You just define a variable called 're'. All variables in Javascript are declared using 'var', not 'int' or a type. Javascript knows no explicit variable types.

The re is probably shorthand for 'regular expression' but you could have used any name and it would still work.

Additionally, if a variable starts and ends with a /, it's a regular expression. Another way to define the regexp is as

```
var re = new RegExp("\s*;\s*");
```

Comment: I understand how variables work it's just the syntax in the variable I'm unfamiliar with. I think regular expressions is what I was looking for. Thanks for your help though @Willem Mulder

Comment: All right :-) Added a small note on how to instantiate a RegExp... Might come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what www.regex101.com says:

```
\s 0 to infinite times [greedy] Whitespace [\t \r\n\f\v]
; Literal ;
\s 0 to infinite times [greedy] Whitespace [\t \r\n\f\v]
```

So you're splitting on `[optional]whitespace followed by a semi-colon followed by [optiona]whitepsace.`

Answer (score 0):

This is a regular expression. To break it down, here is what it is doing:

- The two outer slashes - `/` - encapsulate the expression. It's just shorthand for new RegExp("

  `\s` means "any whitespace."

  `\s*` means "0 or more times."

  `;` is just a semicolon ;)

So the whole expression matches any string that has zero or more whitespace characters followed by a semicolon, then 0 or more whitespace characters.